# Dispaly local html file with iframe in react

Tags: reactjs, iframe

How do I make an iframe display a local html file from a React component. My problem is that when i point to my locale html file the react router picks up the request and redirect to the main page. So the iframe shows the main page instead of the static html page.

Answer (score 7):

try moving the *HTML file to the Public folder*, and then put *`"./yourfile.html"` as the source for the iframe*. though i dont know if this is the best practice or not, but it solves my problem.