# Loading a HTML file in an iframe in React application throws error

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I try to load a HTML file in an iframe in a React application. The HTML file is inside the public folder (directly within public folder). When I run the app though and try to access the route corresponding to the iframe, say `/case/:id/iframe`, I get the following error:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

My code looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Iframe =() =>{
  const iframeSrc = `/search.html`;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-left iframe-window">
        <p className="label-t">Search</p>
            <div className="content-area">
              <iframe
                title="SearchIframe"
                id="iframe"
                src={iframeSrc}
              ></iframe>
            </div>
     </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Iframe;
```

Can someone point out what is the mistake and how to solve it?

Thanks,
Paddy

I searched for the exact error message in a few Stackoverflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580362/dispaly-local-html-file-with-iframe-in-react) but the scenarios mentioned in those cases seemed different from mine.

Comment: Try relative path like - `"./search.html"`